# Пагинация на html, css, jquery без перезагрузки страницы

Tags: html, css, jquery, bootstrap, pagination

Есть кнопки пагинации и блок, который нужно сделать с постраничным выводом без перезагрузки страницы.
Код пагинации:

```
<div class='pages-block>
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
    <div>4</div>
    <div>5</div>
    <div>6</div>
    <div>7</div>
    <div>8</div>
</div>
<div class='container d-flex justify-content-center pagination mt-4'>
    <div class='page-item mx-1 active'>1</div>
    <div class='page-item mx-1'>2</div>
    <div class='page-item mx-1'>3</div>
    <div class='page-item mx-1'>4</div>
</div>
```

Код блока - произвольный. К примеру, 8 div'ов, которые нужно разбить по 4 элемента на страницу. Гуглю, гуглю, куча информации про реализацию кнопок пагинации, а про сам функционал - не нашел ничего толкового. Выручайте!

Comment: наверное стоит попробовать прочитать еще и раздел справки _"nav"_ в части где про использование дата-атрибутов

Comment: _"Код блока - произвольный. К примеру, 8 div'ов"_ вот уж прям произвольный контент вы маловероятно что разобьете на что либо. Конкретизируйте что, по какому критерию и на сколько частей вы собираетесь разбивать.

Comment: @teran, блок с карточками с информацией. Для него нужна пагинация. Это вроде бы не особо отличается от произвольных блоков, они всё равно же реализованы через блоки.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Спасибо за помощь в поиске. Делюсь ответом:

`codepen.io/monkeytempal/pen/pVrwLN`

Помог плагин simplePagination.js.